# Linux-wget command for certain time

Tags: wget

I am using wget command for download in terminal
Is there an option in the wget command that the download starts at a certain date and time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Is there an option in the wget command that the download starts at a certain date and time?*

So far I know no, you might use [`at`](https://linuxize.com/post/at-command-in-linux/) to launch any command at predefined time. Simple example usage: download https://www.example.com at 12:00

```
echo "wget https://www.example.com" | at 12:00
```

Note that you need to activate `atd` (daemon, see linked article) before using `at`. If you want to know more about possible ways of specifying time read [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)  of `at`.